# Agora Video calling local view doesn't start, warning: invalid local view

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am developing a voice/video-calling app using Flutter and Agora rtc engine (v 5.3.1). I have followed all the necessary steps for generating token and joining a channel. But, I can't see the local camera view in the UI and the logs gives me warning saying: "onWarning warn 8 msg invalid view for local video". Any leads would be big help, thanks in advance.

Logs:

```
W/spdlog  (30579): [2023-01-04 21:02:33.375] [0] [warning] /tmp/jenkins/IRIS-SDK/rtc/cxx/src/internal/rtc_engine_event_handler.cc:43 onWarning warn 8 msg invalid view for local video
W/spdlog  (30579): [2023-01-04 21:02:33.375] [0] [warning] /tmp/jenkins/IRIS-SDK/rtc/cxx/src/internal/rtc_engine_event_handler.cc:43 onWarning warn 16 
msg nullptr
I/spdlog  (30579): [2023-01-04 21:02:33.375] [0] [info] /tmp/jenkins/IRIS-SDK/rtc/cxx/src/internal/rtc_engine_event_handler.cc:72 onJoinChannelSuccess 
channel b8667da0-8c6a-11ed-a9fb-578e8ad35bd6 uid 1
W/spdlog  (30579): [2023-01-04 21:02:33.377] [0] [warning] /tmp/jenkins/IRIS-SDK/rtc/cxx/src/internal/rtc_engine_event_handler.cc:43 onWarning warn 16 
msg nullptr
```

Call Screen Widget:

```
imports...

String baseUrl = 'https://...';

class CallScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final Call call;
   
  const CallScreen({Key? key, required this.call, }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CallScreenState createState() => _CallScreenState();
}

class _CallScreenState extends ConsumerState<CallScreen> {
  int uid = 1;
  List<int> _remoteUids = [];
  bool isJoined = false, 
      switchCamera = true,
      openMicrophone = true,
      enableSpeakerphone = false;
  late bool openCamera; 
  late RtcEngine _engine;

  @override
  void initState() { 
    initAgora();
    openCamera = widget.call.isVideoCall;
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<String?> _getToken() async {
    String url = baseUrl + "/rtc/" + widget.call.callId + "/publisher/uid/" + uid.toString() + "/";;
    String? token;
    try{
      var resp = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if(resp.statusCode == 200){
        token = jsonDecode(resp.body)['rtcToken'];
        return token;
      }
      else{
        showMySnackBar(context: context, content: "Token Status ERR: "+jsonDecode(resp.body)['message']);
        return null;
      }
    } 
    catch(e){
      showMySnackBar(context: context, content: "Token Err: "+e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  void _joinChannel() async {
    String? token = await _getToken();

    if(token != null){
      await _engine.joinChannel(token, widget.call.callId, null, uid);
    }
    else{
      showMySnackBar(context: context, content: 'Token is null!');
    }
  }

  void  _leaveChannel() async {
    ref.read(callControllerProvider).endCall(
      widget.call.callerId, 
      widget.call.receiverId, 
      context, 
      widget.call.isGroupChat
    );

    if(widget.call.isVideoCall) await _engine.stopPreview();

    await _engine.leaveChannel();
  }

  void _switchCamera() {
    _engine.switchCamera()
    .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        switchCamera = !switchCamera;
      });
    })
    .catchError((err) {
      //print('switchCamera $err');
    });
  }

  void _switchMicrophone() async {
    // await _engine.muteLocalAudioStream(!openMicrophone);
    await _engine.enableLocalAudio(!openMicrophone)
    .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        openMicrophone = !openMicrophone;
      });
    })
    .catchError((err) {
      // print('enableLocalAudio $err');
    });
  }

  void _switchSpeakerphone() {
    _engine.setEnableSpeakerphone(!enableSpeakerphone)
    .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        enableSpeakerphone = !enableSpeakerphone;
      });
    })
    .catchError((err) {
      //print('setEnableSpeakerphone $err');
    });
  }
  
  void initAgora() async {
    try{
    await [Permission.microphone, Permission.camera].request();

    _engine = await RtcEngine.createWithContext(RtcEngineContext(AgoraConfig.appId));

    _engine.setEventHandler(
      RtcEngineEventHandler(
        warning: (warn) {
          showMySnackBar(context: context, content: "Warn: "+warn.name);
        },
        error: (err) {
          showMySnackBar(context: context, content: 'OnErr event: '+err.name);
        },
        joinChannelSuccess: (String channel, int userId, int elapsed) {
          // print("local user ${connection.localUid} joined");
          if(mounted){
            setState(() {
              isJoined = true;
              uid = userId;
            });
          }
          showMySnackBar(context: context, content: 'You ($userId) have joined the call!');
        },
        userJoined: (int remoteUid, int elapsed) {
          //debugPrint("remote user $remoteUid joined");
          if(mounted){
          setState(() {
            _remoteUids.add(remoteUid);
          });
          }
        },
        userOffline: (int remoteUid, UserOfflineReason reason) {
          //debugPrint("remote user $remoteUid left channel");
          if(mounted){
          setState(() {
            _remoteUids.removeWhere((element) => element == remoteUid);
          });
          }
        },
        leaveChannel: (stats) {
          if(mounted){
          setState(() {
            isJoined = false;
            if(!widget.call.isGroupChat || _remoteUids.length == 1){
              _remoteUids.clear();
            }
          });
          }
        },
        // onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire: (RtcConnection connection, String token) {
        //   debugPrint('[onTokenPrivilegeWillExpire] connection: ${connection.toJson()}, token: $token');
        // },
      ),
    );

    await _engine.setChannelProfile(ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting);
    //await _engine.setClientRole(ClientRole.Broadcaster);
    await _engine.enableVideo();
    if(widget.call.isVideoCall){
      await _engine.startPreview();
    }
    else{
      await _engine.muteLocalVideoStream(true);
      await _engine.muteAllRemoteVideoStreams(true);
    }
    
    _joinChannel();
    }
    catch(e){
      showMySnackBar(context: context, content: "Init Err: "+e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _leaveChannel();
    _engine.destroy();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Display remote user's video
  Widget _remoteVideo() {
    if (_remoteUids.isNotEmpty) {
      //TODO check for video on or off or if video call:
      return rtc_remote_view.SurfaceView(
        uid: _remoteUids[0],
        channelId: widget.call.callId,
      );
    } 
    else {
      return const Text(
        'Please wait for others to join',
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      );
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async { _leaveChannel(); return true; },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: _remoteVideo(),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 18.0, bottom: 12),
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                  child: ColoredBox(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                    child: ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 125, maxHeight: 175),
                      child: AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: 9/16,
                        child: Center(
                          child: isJoined
                              ? 
                              ( //TODO: check for video on or off or if video call:
                                openCamera 
                                ? rtc_local_view.SurfaceView(
                                  channelId: widget.call.callId,
                                )
                                : const Icon(
                                    Icons.videocam_off_rounded, 
                                    color: Colors.black, 
                                    size: appActionsIconsSize,
                                  )
                              )
                              : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ali99, When i had started it with reactjs. I had to do two things.
1- Create a container in UI 
2- Dont forget to give the container Height and width. May be it can help.

Comment: Hi @Furquan Thank you for reply. I tried replacing the Align widget with a Container with width and height in the UI but no luck. I don't think it is a UI rendering issue though.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: I was not setting the `ClientRoleType` correctly and that caused error in finding local view. One needs to define `ClientRoleType` (based on your logic) and `ChannelProfileType.broadcast` and everything seems to work.